# ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Error when trying to install some packages using conda command. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to install `[EQcorrscan][1]` on  my new conda environment. Steps to reproduce:

Open Terminal

```
conda install colorama numpy scipy matplotlib obspy bottleneck pyproj
```

Got error messages:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::colorama-0.4.3-py_0'.
FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/home/yongki/anaconda3/envs/obspy3/bin/python3.6'")
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/home/yongki/anaconda3/envs/obspy3/bin/python3.6'")
```

Looked for solution on the internet, still no answer.

Comment: Is it only `colorama` that fails? If so, you could reduce the `conda install …` to the packages that fail.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, it remains failed for the`colorama`.

Comment: Can you try installing the packages when you create environment? Are you sure the environment was activated?